# jQuery / javascript variable in if statement not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I have a variable as such:

```
var is_last = $('.paging a:last').attr('rel');
```

this returns '-400' which is correct.

However, i need to add 200 to this so the answer is '-200'

if i do this:

```
var is_last = $('.paging a:last').attr('rel')+200;
```

the variable is now '-400200'

How can i pass the variable as a value?

A.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to parse the output of [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), it to an integer first using [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) so you're dealing with a number (and not a string), like this:

```
var is_last = parseInt($('.paging a:last').attr('rel'), 10) + 200;
```

Answer (score 0):

I reckon that @Nick Craver is correct and that parseInt is the more correct answer, but as a quick-and-dirty alternative you can also convince javascript that a variable is a number and not a string by multiplying by 1:

```
    var x = parseInt("-400", 10) + 200;
    var y = ("-400" * 1) + 200;

    alert(x);
    alert(y);
```

Comment: You *can* do this, but it's much slower, [you can test it here](http://jsperf.com/number-vs-parseint-vs-plus/3), `+"-400"` would be the operator shortcut with decent performance here :)

Comment: Very good comparison tool, the marked improvement in js performance on Chrome 8 compared to Chrome 7 suggests that I should upgrade immediately.  Also it is odd how the 6 different techniques would result in markedly different performance in different browsers or versions of browsers - on my Chrome 7 setup, parseInt is the slowest on those benchmarks.  Thanks again I will use this reference in conversations!